# Spatial join is outputting seemingly incorrect result in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am attempting what I thought was a straightforward operation in ArcMap. I have a polygon layer where some polygons overlap. I also have a polyline layer. I would like to spatially join the polygon layer with the polyline layer using a "WITHIN" relationship.

The objective is to make sure every polyline which is either fully or partially within a polygon layer takes on the attribute from the (partially containing polygon). This is what the spatial join dialog looks like:

[image]

What I do see, however, is that many polylines do not obtain a containing polygon attribute and get a 0 instead. This occurs mostly in polygon border crossings and when a significant portion of the segment lies outside the polygon.

[image]

Which is very confusing because it implies that "WITHIN" and "COMPLETELY WITHIN" have the same behavior? I thought that "WITHIN" implied that even target features partially within the join features get matched...

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way?

Comment: It is "partly  within". Intersect does not guarantee what I need... what if the line is fully within, yet does not intersect the polygon? I still want that to match...

Comment: A line crossing a polygon border is not within, look at [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C99C9DD7EB234B85B756CDE2C2A1CD76). Try intersect instead. If line is fully inside polygon they still intersect

Comment: Should go to accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line crossing a polygon border is not within. Use intersect instead:

> The features in the join features will be matched if they intersect a
>   target feature

Look at a description of the spatial queries [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C99C9DD7EB234B85B756CDE2C2A1CD76)